# HTML/JS : Required input X ignored if input Y is filled

Tags: javascript, html

Good day!

So I have a simple HTML form which has 4 inputs:

name | email | name2 | email2

Currently all the fields are required but, is it possible that if I fill the first two inputs (name, email), the required other inputs (name2, email2) can be left blank, and the other way around too ..

Here's my code

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <table background="images/bg.jpg" align="center" style="height: 295px;  width: 800px;" border="0">
        <tbody>
    <tr>
    <!------------------------------- Individual ------------------------------>
        <p style="text-align: left; "><b>Name</b>
        <input name="name" style="height:30px;" type="text" value="" placeholder="" required="required" /><img src="jvk/button.gif"></p>
      <p style="text-align: left; "><b>Email</b>
      <input name="email" style="height:30px;" type="text" value="" placeholder="" required="required" />;
      <button class="indiv" type="submit">Submit ></button>
      </p>
   </td>
   <!------------------------------- Enterprise ------------------------------>
    <td style="width: 297px;">
    <p style="text-align: left;">-<b>Company name</b>
    <br />
        <input name="name2" type="text" value=""  style="height:30px;" placeholder="" required="required" /><img src="jvk/button.gif"></p>
        <p>-<b>Email<br/>
        <input name="email2" type="text" value="" style="height:30px;" placeholder="" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" class="busin">Submit ></button></p>
</td>
</tr>
```

For now, I can't move on until the 4 inputs are filled, I have been searching for the solution but since I have no skills in programming I couldn't fix it.

Please help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you might be better using javascript validation, then you can just check for name and email. See here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this after the user has inputted the data and it will disable the "required" attribute for the "Individual" or "Enterprise" depending on which two input tags are filled.

```js
function checkRequired(){
 if(document.querySelector("[name=name]").value != "" && document.querySelector("[name=email]").value != ""){
  document.querySelector("[name=name2]").required  = false;
  document.querySelector("[name=email2]").required = false;
 }else{
  document.querySelector("[name=name]").required  = false;
  document.querySelector("[name=email]").required = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lance, 
I tried to add the script, it solved part of the problem, when I fill name and email, the other 2 inputs (name2, email2) aren't required anymore, but .. when I fill name2 and email2 it still asks me to fill the first 2 inputs (name, email)

Comment: I updated the code to look for the value in the input tag.